# I installed wingpanel on elementary (Jupiter) and its opening the folder /usr/share/applications

Tags: wingpanel

I installed wingpanel and when i click on 'Apps', it opens the /usr/share/applications folder
what am i missing? is this the expected behavior? shouldn't it open the launcher?
thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have slingshot installed?
If not this probably causes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wingpanel is in active development and not yet considered stable.  It is also not apart of Ubuntu but a primary piece of ElementaryOS an Ubuntu derived distro.  Please file this question as a bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/wingpanel/+filebug?NOREDIRECT

Answer (score 0):

i guess slingshot is incompatible with my version of elementary (based on ubuntu 10.10)
i tried install slingshot, but apt-get says that can't found on any repositories...